How to Insert sitecore edge (cloud) item using graphql from react client app

Experience Edge for Experience Manager (XM)
Sitecore-hosted GraphQL API.
React client(azure hosted pm2 static react web app service).

I am creating a Contact Us form page on a public site developed on React, hosted on Azur (pm2 node). I'm using GraphQL to Sitecore edge items to render on pages, PDFs, and images from the media library. Except for one page other page's content are delivered from Sitecore edge from Sitecore tree (pages and global), which means getting data.
On one page we have details in Sitecore using GraphQL from React client we need to add an item.
I have tried a documented approach of Adding using mutation as described in
https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/query-examples-for-authoring-operations.html
Please let me know if someone has solved this for Sitecore could using GraphQL

Do you want to create a item using graphql ? your question is not clear can you please rephrase it?
So far I understood that  you are not getting data of one page from edge is my understanding correct ?
